# Should I use ANDROID_ID as device identification considering no factory reset?

Tags: android, unique-id, android-identifiers, deviceid, device-instance-id

I am developing an Android app where a single user can use the app only in one device by using the same Gmail account(for sign-in) . If the user wants to sign in the app on a different device, he won't be able to do it using the same Gmail account. I am using ANDROID_ID in my application to identify a unique device using the following command--

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Is it the correct option in this case, since I have seen in the developer website that

```
    Avoid using hardware identifiers. In most use cases, you can avoid using hardware identifiers, such as 
SSAID (Android ID), without limiting required functionality.

             Android 10 (API level 29) adds restrictions for non-resettable dentifiers, which include both 
            IMEI and serial number. Your app must be a device or profile owner app, have
         special carrier permissions, or have the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE privileged permission
     in order to access these identifiers.
```

Link for the doc-

```
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids
```

Or is there any other way for doing the above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more information on how the ID would be checked. Does the app perform actions locally or is it continually interacting with a server? If a new device tries to sign on with the same account should it be denied access or should the old device be logged out?

Answer (score 2):

If possible use [FirebaseInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) in your use case. Firebase Instance ID provides a unique identifier for each app instance and a mechanism to authenticate and authorize actions.

1. Instance ID is stable except when:
2. App deletes Instance ID
3. App is restored on a new device
4. User uninstalls/reinstall the app
5. User clears app data

In case if you don't want to use FirebaseInstanceId, you can look for custom globally-unique IDs (GUIDs) to uniquely identify an app instance.

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

You can use this GUID for identifying if only one device is attached to a gmail id or not.

Answer (score 0):

you  can define your own rule  to  generate a unqiue id，then  save it on  sp.  every  time  you should check，get it and  compare  with the data that service provide.

or you  can also use  advicement ID to as unqiue device id.